# Reverse Installation of Tomcat on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

I've installed Tomcat on Ubuntu using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04). It works, so I'm able to see the default page at [localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080).

For some reason I need to remove it completely from my machine now.

How can I reverse the installation?

Comment: You'd get a ton of examples on Google for uninstalling Tomcat if you didn't invent a new term (revert installation) for it

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

```
sudo systemctl stop tomcat
sudo rm -r /opt/tomcat
sudo rm /etc/init/tomcat.conf
sudo systemctl reload-configuration
```

This will only remove tomcat and not the `jdk`(Java) that you installed. You might want to keep it if you're going to install another version of Tomcat, or any other programs that need JDK to run. Also, the user `tomcat` you created will still remain.